# c# json rearrange with same value

Tags: c#, json

How do u make the below json in c#

```
[
 {"file": "fileName1", "key":0, title:"u1"},
 {"file": "fileName1", "key":2, title:"u1"},
 {"file": "fileName2", "key":5, title:"u1"},
 {"file": "fileName2", "key":10, title:"u1"}
]
```

into this.

```
{ 
 "fileName1" : [{"key":0, title:"u1"},{"key":2, title:"u1"}],
 "fileName2" : [{"key":0, title:"u1"},{"key":2, title:"u1"}]
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Well, the latter looks like it's effectively a `Dictionary<string, List<SomeNewType>>`. Basically I'd deserialize to one type, convert it to another type, then serialize that. Have you tried any of that? If so, where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done  a .NEt fiddle for you requirement
https://dotnetfiddle.net/Wsnl9V

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string input = @"[ 
             {'file': 'fileName1', 'key':0, title:'u1'},
             {'file': 'fileName1', 'key':2, title:'u1'},
             {'file': 'fileName2', 'key':5, title:'u1'},
             {'file': 'fileName2', 'key':10, title:'u1'}
        ]";

        var existingList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CurrentType>>(input);

        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string,List<RequiredTypeFile>>();


        var distinctFileNames =  existingList.Select(x=> x.File).Distinct().ToList();

        distinctFileNames.ForEach(x=>
                                  {
                                      var fileValue = existingList.Where(m=>m.File==x)
                                        .Select(m => new RequiredTypeFile
                                                {
                                                    Key = m.Key,
                                                    Title = m.Title
                                                }).ToList();
                                      dictionary.Add(x,fileValue);
                                  });

        var reqdJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary);


        Console.WriteLine(reqdJson);
    }
}

public class CurrentType
{
    public string File
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int Key
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class RequiredTypeFile
{
    public int Key
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

}